# How do I use $emit in the loop to pass the array value to the parent?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

The child component will pass the value to the parent component through a loop
And the parent component will do something with the value

I have a mistake, the parent component cannot receive the child component, and each passed value will be missing

child component

```
 let array =[{a:'1',b:'2'},{a:'3',b:'4'},{a:'5',b:'6'},{a:'1',b:'2'},....]
 for(let index in array){
     this.$emit('update', array[index])
 }
```

parent component

```
 update(product) {
     console.log(product);
 }
```

In my console I can only get part of the children pass value

What is this error and how can I fix it？

This is my sample, although the error cannot be reproduced, the code is the same, except that the parent does not display all

[example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/happy-mclean-3rxvnh?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Why don't you simply update the whole array?

Comment: Because, the update function in parent is used in many places

Comment: Just to be sure: The update function isn't called automatically. You have to add a handler for the update: `@update="update"` where you add the child component. See [documentation of component events](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#emitting-and-listening-to-events).

Comment: If you can't reproduce your error in your own reproduction sample, we can't really help here. Try to debug your code using the developer console + vue devtools extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work fine, I did not see any issue in your code. I am assuming you are capturing the event emitted from the child into the parent component like this.

```
<child @update="update"></child>
```

Working Demo **:**

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  data() {
    return {
      arr: [{a:'1',b:'2'}, {a:'3',b:'4'}, {a:'5',b:'6'},{a:'1',b:'2'}]
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    for(let index in this.arr){
      this.$emit('update', this.arr[index])
    }
  }
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    update(product) {
        console.log(product);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.0/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <child @update="update"></child>
</div>
```

***Suggestion :*** To improve the performance, Instead of emitting each element into parent component, My suggestion would be to pass whole array and then do the data manipulations in the parent component itself.